# Make a Picturebox Appear on Mouse Location When Moused is Clicked in C#

Tags: c#, picturebox, mouseclick-event

I have made a program that measures distances from two user placed pictureboxes. At the moment it all works fine except, where i want the dots to go the pictureboxes do not go into that location where i clicked. This is my current code in Mouseclick event of the picturebox the two dots (pictureboxes) are to be placed and measure in:

```
if (Dotter == 1)
        {
            dot1.Visible = true;
            dot1.Location = e.Location;
            Dotter = 2;
        }
        else if (Dotter == 2)
        {
            dot2.Visible = true;
            dot2.Location = e.Location;
            Dotter = 1;
        }
```

This is the actual placing function for the two pictureboxes at the moment, please help.

Thanks

Extra Info:

It is in the picturebox where the image which can be measured using these two dots, and is in its mouseclick event, and its on a Windows Form. Also when i click they are placed but are miles away from where i clicked, and sometimes even appear outside the picturebox when they shouldn't be.

Comment: Can you share more code?  More specifically, the event handler in which the above code resides.  Also, what control are you clicking on? The form? Or another `PictureBox`?

Comment: Is this a windows forms app? If so, I do believe that the `location` property determines the top-left of the picture box. This could be affecting the behaviour.

Comment: another question: when you say "they do not go where I clicked" you mean they go somewhere else? Or don't go anywhere?

Comment: Basically it makes the 'dot' pictureboxes go far left from where i clicked and sometimes out of the main picturebox where they should stay in and not be shown out of it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help this is what i have done to make it work. I have changed the e.Location part of my code to this:

if (Dotter == 1)
            {
                dot1.Visible = true;
                dot1.Left = e.Location.X + capturebox.Left - 10;
                dot1.Top = e.Location.Y + capturebox.Top - 10;
                Dotter = 2;
            }
            else if (Dotter == 2)
            {
                dot2.Visible = true;
                dot2.Left = e.Location.X + capturebox.Left - 10;
                dot2.Top = e.Location.Y + capturebox.Top - 10;
                Dotter = 1;
            }

So basically changing the dot's locations to Left and Top and then getting the mouse click location for x and y and then made the point at which the dot will appear to be in the middle of it by minusing 10 from each.